# configure SSL in HapiContext (Hapi-base 2.3)

Tags: ssl, spring-cloud-dataflow, hapi

In one of our spring boot apps used in Springcloud dataflow streams, we are currently using HapiContext to construct a new HL7 client and establish a connection out of it to send HL7 messages to a TCP host and port.

```
@Autowired
HapiContext context;

Connection connection = context.newClient(host, Integer.parseInt(port), false);
 
// The initiator which will be used to transmit our message
    Initiator initiator = connection.getInitiator();

    Message response = initiator.sendAndReceive(adtMessage);
```

Currently we are not using SSL/TLS for this connection and call. but we now have a requirement such that the call should be changed to an SSL based one.

I have tried doing a lot of searches on the Internet, but I am not able to find any documentation on how to achieve this.

Is there anyway to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating the HapiContext?

The DefaultHapiContext seems to provide for creating a client with a tls parameter.

Comment: `new DefaultHapiContext()` - i'm using the DefaultHapiContext.

`Connection connection = context.newClient(host, Integer.parseInt(port), false);`

In the above statement the third boolean parameter is for enabling TLS. i tried to pass true as a value for third paremeter. But still, it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

lookup for the ca.uhn.hl7v2.hoh.sockets.CustomCertificateTlsSocketFactory, this should have createClientSocket which will add the SSL context necessary

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).